# page redirect is not working for ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have 4 ContentPage in my application portable class 
PageA
PageB
PageC
PageD

Page a to page b come with

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new PageB(),this); 
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

From Page b to Page c redirect from code

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new PageC(),this); 
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

From Page C to Page D redirect from code

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new PageD(),this); 
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Now I want to redirect the user from PageD To PageB

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new PageB(),this); 
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

I can come from PageA to PageD very smoothly. But trying to return from PageD to PageB I am getting an exception

Error
**before must be in the pushed stack of the current context**

**Stack track**

> at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationProxy.OnInsertPageBefore
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, Xamarin.Forms.Page before) [0x00020] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:150    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationProxy.InsertPageBefore
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, Xamarin.Forms.Page before) [0x00000] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationProxy.cs:59    at
>   Test.PageD+d__9.MoveNext () [0x0007a] in
>   E:\Projects\xamrine\Source\TestiOS\PictureAfterSignature.xaml.cs:433

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to navigate this way :

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new PageA());

// In Page A
Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
Navigation.RemovePage(this);

// In Page B
Navigation.PushAsync(new PageC());

// In Page C
Navigation.PushAsync(new PageD());
Navigation.RemovePage(this);
```

Now if you see, PageB and PageD are only Pages in the Navigation stack.

In PageD, when you want to navigate to B, just call :

```
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

// PopAsync - removes the most recent page in stack.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Before calling the "await Navigation.PopAsync();", please debug and see in iOS, what value is there in the Navigation stack. You will get an idea on what pages are there in stack and you can easily tackle it.

Comment: P Shetty I have checked the navigation Stack in debugin mode its null

Comment: Can you try my code once and see if it gives you the expected behavior ?

Comment: Which line did you check `NavigationStack` ? @A.Goutam

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT on PageD

Comment: which line , before `InsertPageBefore` or after.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT before InsertPageBefore